# What to implement counter in php

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I want to show the counter..
I am writing a where we are updating database records.

I am printing counter values here --

```
            flush();
            echo "<hr><div align=\"center\">";
            echo 'loading ..... '.$counter; //echo "</br>";
            echo "</div>";
            $counter++;
```

But it is printing values in next line again again..

[image]

But I want values to be updated like this
[image]

This one will keep changing..

Help me out or guide me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is *generating* HTML; once it's been written there's no "taking it back."

In order to have your counter "update," you will need to perform what is known as Document Object Model manipulation (the DOM really is everything your website is made up of, including, of course, all the HTML tags). This is normally done with JavaScript, and jQuery can simplify the task even further.

Furthermore, your database inserts will take place so quickly (in fractions of a second) that there really is no reason to show a counter of the updates taking place "real-time" before your users.

If you truly insist on having information on your site dynamically updated as PHP is executed, you will need to look into AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript in order to do this. You could use something like :

```
    flush();
    echo "<hr><div align=\"center\">";
    echo 'loading ..... '. '<span class = "toDecr">' . $counter . '</span>';
    echo "</div>";
    $counter++;
```

And then create a script using jQuery doing this (jQuery is not mandatory, you could do it in raw Javascript, but jQuery is definitely easier IMHO) :

```
    $('.toDecr').html(parseInt($('.toDecr').html(), 10) - 1)
```

I don't know the delay you want to wait between the decrements, so I let it blank for you (if you want to do it every second then just use a loop, or if it's really dependent on the execution of your PHP, Ajax is the way to go).

Comment: what if i don't want to use jQuery... My values are updating at the time of server response.. and i want to show those at the client side as they loaded..

Comment: So you have to go for AJAX ;)